# Token based authentication in a asp.net core mvc web application using web api

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a .net core 2.2 web application in which database calls are handled through a web api. I am trying authenticate my application using web api. I have generated a JWT token at my web api. but I am not able to retrieve that token at my web application.

How can I use the token issued by web api in my web application for accessing further modules?

Thanks in advance!

code in my web application:

```
Task<OkObjectResult> ValidUser = commonHelper.CheckValidUserToken(identity);
```

Code returning token from web api:

```
OkObjectResult tokenObject = Ok(
    new
    {
        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
        expiration = token.ValidTo
    });
return tokenObject;
```

I need to get the token for accessing the controllers in web api. Now i am getting a Task.

Comment: can you please elaborate , web application does not receive token? or are you not able to authenticate using the token

Comment: Actually I managed to get the token in my web application. Since I am totally new to this technology, I am not sure how to authenticate using the token. Any lead/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In General , you client will send HTTP request to web api side with your credential , web api will validate the credential , create the token and send back to your client .

You didn't provide the client codes . According to your web api returned `OkObjectResult`, you can firstly create object class like :

```
public class Value
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string expiration { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Value value { get; set; }

    public int statusCode { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize json string which read from response to object , get token value like :

```
// call api
var apiClient = new HttpClient();

var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44348/api/values");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    RootObject rootObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

    var token = rootObject.value.token;

}
```

We don't know what is the `CheckValidUserToken` function , but you should check how client app send the token request and read the response .

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have created a class for the token and I could pass the value back to my web apllication.

Comment: @Reshma, so what's your problem ? If you don't know how to use token to access web api method , just append token as http client request authorization header : 
            var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

Comment: Now it is working as expected. Thanks for providing me the solution.